# Android Bitmap factory returns null when trying to read a decoded Base64 jpeg

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, jpeg

I have retrieved a jpeg image from a web service using an HTTP GET call, and I need to display it in an ImageView, but it is encoded in Base64. Therefore, I used the following code to convert it:

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(imageStringInBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

However, I get the error: `--- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null`

When logged to the console, *imageStringInBase64* looks like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ ... a bunch of stuff ... /B6TTbssco
```

Comment: Try to save it to SD and see if you can open it on your computer or via gallery app.

Comment: If `data:image...` is the value in `imageStringInBase64` then that won't work. You need just the base64 encoded data (everything after the last comma).

Comment: @dmon That was it. I split the string and used everything after the comma, and it worked.

Comment: @dmon you should add your answer below (it's an answer, not a comment) and then Groppe can accept it. This will help future visitors to this question.

Comment: Yeah, I was unsure of the exact value of the string, hence the comment. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `data:image...` is the value in `imageStringInBase64` then that won't work. You need just the base64 encoded data (everything after the last comma).